# Sum of convex and decreasing function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a sum of decreasing function and a convex function over some domain. Can I say that the sum is also a convex function (i.e. there exists a unique minimum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x^2$ is convex and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}-x^2$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$, but $f(x)+g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, which is concave.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearly providing an example in the answer. Can you provide some comments on this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844377/optimization-of-the-function-of-two-variables

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know too much about optimization, so it's not so clear to me how to solve that problem.